# Prove inequalities involving norms in polynomial ring

Tags: polynomials, normed-spaces

Let $f,g,h \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ with degrees $n \geq 1,m,k$ respectively and assume that $gh | f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Prove that

$$||g||_1||h||_1 \leq 2^{m+k}||f||_2 \leq (n+1)^{1/2} \cdot 2^{m+k} ||f||_{\infty}$$

Derive from this that

$$||h||_\infty \leq ||h||_2 \leq 2^k ||f||_2 \leq 2^k||f||_1$$
and
$$||h||_\infty \leq ||h||_2 \leq (n+1)^{1/2} \cdot 2^k ||f||_\infty$$

I know the definitions of the norms however I don't understand where the $2^{m+k}$ in the first inequality comes from for example. What does the fact of the product of the two polynomials dividing the other tell me about the coefficients? I'm thankful for any tip!

Edit: This is how far I've got with the first one:

$$||g||_1||h||_1 \leq \sum_{i=1}^m |f_i| \sum_{i=1}^k |f_i|$$ because the coefficients of $g,h$ divide those of $f$ and so the absolute sum of the coefficients has to be greater or equal. Then this is

$$\leq (\sum_{i=1}^{m+k} |f_i|)^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{m+k} |f_i|^2 \sum_{i=1}^{m+k} 1^2 \leq (m+k) \sum_{i=1}^{n} |f_i|^2$$

by Cauchy-Schwartz and the fact that $m+k$ has to be less or equal than $n$.